# Swapping variables in mixed integer programming

Tags: logic, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Suppose I have a binary variables $b$ and two real variables $x$ and $y$ is there a way to assign $z_1=\min(x,y)$ and $z_2=\max(x,y)$ using mixed integer linear programming?

This is my attempt. Assume $-M<x,y<M$. Then let
$$-bM\leq x'\leq bM$$
$$x-(1-b)M\leq x'\leq x+ (1-b)M$$

$$-(1-b)M\leq x''\leq (1-b)M$$
$$x-bM\leq x''\leq x+ bM$$

$$-(1-b)M\leq y'\leq (1-b)M$$
$$y-bM\leq y'\leq y+ bM$$

$$-bM\leq y''\leq bM$$
$$y-(1-b)M\leq y''\leq y+ (1-b)M$$

$$z_1=x'+y'$$
$$z_2=x''+y''$$
$$z_1\leq z_2.$$

Is there anything simpler than this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need $x'$ and $y'$:
$$x - 2bM \leq z_1 \leq x + 2bM$$
$$y - 2(1-b)M \leq z_1 \leq y + 2(1-b)M$$
$$x - 2(1-b)M \leq z_2 \leq x + 2(1-b)M$$
$$y - 2bM \leq z_2 \leq y + 2bM$$
$$z_1 \leq z_2.$$
Depending how the minimum and maximum are used, you may not need a binary variable. For example:
$$\max\{x,y\} \leq z$$
is equivalent to:
$$x \leq z$$
$$y \leq z.$$

Comment: So in this case $b=0$ means $x\leq y$ and $b=1$ means $x\geq y$?

Comment: I want exact assignment and so $x\leq z$ and $y\leq z$ will not work.

Comment: Why $2b$ and $2(1-b)$ and not just $b$ and $(1-b)$ respectively?

Comment: @1.. yes @ interpretation of $b$. You need the factor $2$ because $2M$ is the largest absolute difference between $x$ and $y$. For example, $y-2(1-b)M \leq z_1$ is tight whenf $x=-M$ and $y=M$.

Comment: @1.. please mark this question as answered if you are satisfied